# Run external processes in non-blocking mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, multithreading, ruby-2.0

I want to perform  some actions in parallel periodically and once they're all done, show the results to the user on a page. It'll happen approximately 1 time per 5 mins, it depends on the users' activity.
These actions are performed by the external, third-party applications (processes). There're about 4 of them now. So I have to run 4 external processes for each user request .
While they are performing, I show an user a page with an ajax spinner and send an ajax requests to the server to check if everything is done. Once done, I show the results.

Here is a rough version of what I have

```
class MyController

  def my_action request_id

    res = external_apps_cmds_with_args.each do |x|

      # new process
      res = Open3.popen3 x do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        exit_value = wait_thr.value.exitstatus
        if exit_value == 0 ....
      end
    end

    write_res_to_db res, request_id #each external app writes to the db its own result for each request_id

  end
end
```

The calculations CAN be done in parallel because there's NO overall result here, there are only the results from each tool. There is no race condition.
So I want them to run in non-blocking mode, obviously.

Is `Open3.popen3` a non-blocking command? Or should I run the external processes in **the different threads**:

```
threads = []
external_apps_cmds_with_args.each do |x|
  # new threads
  threads << Thread.new do

    # new process
    res = Open3.popen3 x do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
      exit_value = wait_thr.value.exitstatus
      if exit_value == 0 ....
    end
  end

  write_res_to_db res, request_id #each external app writes to the db its own result for each request_id    
end

threads.each &:join
```

Or should I create **only one** thread?

```
# only one new thread
thread = Thread.new do
   res = external_apps_cmds_with_args.each do |x|
      # new process
      res = Open3.popen3 x do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        exit_value = wait_thr.value.exitstatus
        if exit_value == 0 ....
      end
    end

    write_res_to_db res, request_id #each external app writes to the db its own result for each request_id    
end

thread.join
```

Or should I continue using the approach I'm using now: NO threads at all?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you have one action to load the page and then a separate ajax action for each process. As the processes finish they will return data to the user (presumably in different parts of the page) and you will take advantage of the multi-process/threading capabilities of your webserver.

This approach has some issues because like your original ideas, you are tying up some of your web processes while the external processes are running and you may run into timeouts. If you want to avoid that, you could run them as background jobs (delayed_job, resque, etc..) and then display the data when the jobs have finished.